# Django rest framrwork assertion error: Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have imported the Django model `Product` into the DRF model serializer class, but I get the error `Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute`. What surprises me is that the model is set on the `Meta` class. What I'm I doing wrong?

### Error

```
AssertionError at /api/products/

Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/products/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     AssertionError
Exception Value:    

Class ProductSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute

Exception Location:     c:\dev\django-paystack\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in get_fields, line 1020
Python Executable:  c:\dev\django-paystack\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.1
Python Path:    

['c:\\dev\\django-paystack',
 'c:\\dev\\django-paystack\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Romeo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Romeo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Romeo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'c:\\dev\\django-paystack\\env',
 'c:\\dev\\django-paystack\\env\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 29 Jul 2020 14:43:24 +0000
```

### Here is the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets, generics
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Product
from .serializer import ProductSerializer


class ProductsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """List products viewset"""

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

### Model Class

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    """Product items"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d", null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    """Order for product item"""

    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, max_length=200, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

### Model serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product, Order


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Products model serializer"""

    class Meta:
        model: Product
        fields: "__all__"


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Order model serializer"""

    class Meta:
        model: Order
        fields: "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax with a `:` is not correct when defining `Meta`, use `=`, as follows:

```
class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: oh wow, I didn't notice that at all. Thanks for the help @little_birdie